# How do i add n custom-cells to my view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a table view, amongst the table, in each row i want to display an image to the extreme left, some string in the middle, a number after that and again a string followed by a number, n all that should be in different font styles and sizes. Now i did this using custom-cells, but that is just for one row, what if user wants to enter data and then view the added info in the next row of the table. How do i add multiple custom cells to my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the datasource of your tableView and call reloadData method

```
[tableView reloadData];
```